# Not able to block total body in template by using PrimeFaces blockui?

Tags: jsf, templates, jsf-2, primefaces

Template.xhtml
total template page

```
<h:body id="homeBody">
    <ui:include src="/template/sessionTimeOut.xhtml" />
    <div id="page">
        <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" id="header" size="65"
                style="overflow: none; height: 65px!important ">
                <ui:insert name="header">
                    <ui:include src="adminheader.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" id="footer" size="40"
                style="text-align: center;">
                <ui:insert name="footer">
                    <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>


            <ui:insert name="content">
                <ui:include src="content.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </p:layout>
    </div>
    <h:outputScript target="body">onload('#{visitorComponent.admin.admin_name}')</h:outputScript>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/js/chat_messages.js"></script>
</h:body>
```

header.xtml
its header part

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form id="headerForm">
            <h:graphicImage url="./images/vms_logo.png" class="header_logo" />
            <span class="header_name"><strong> Visitor Management
                    System</strong></span>

            <p:growl id="msgs" />
            <p:commandLink rendered="#{visitorComponent.admin.role == 'user'}"
                action="#{visitorComponent.getOperatorMessages1}" update="newlabel"
                style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;">
                <h:outputText value="Messages" />
                <h:outputText value="new" rendered="#{visitorComponent.newmsg}"
                    id="newlabel"></h:outputText>
            </p:commandLink>

            <p:poll interval="15" listener="#{visitorComponent.schedular}"
                update="headerForm" />
            <p:commandButton value="Home" id="homeBtn"
                action="#{visitorComponent.goHomePage}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-home"
                styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />

            <p:blockUI block=":homeBody" trigger="homeBtn">
                <p:graphicImage name="icon/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </p:blockUI>

            <p:commandButton value="New Visitor"
                action="#{visitorComponent.addVisitor}"
                icon="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />

            <p:commandButton value="Check Visitor"
                action="#{visitorComponent.checkVisitor}"
                icon="ui-icon-white ui-icon-pencil" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />

            <p:commandButton value="Search"
                action="#{autoCompleteServices.searchVisitor}"
                icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />

            <div id="user_account" align="right" style="">
                <h:graphicImage url="./images/employee_icon.png"
                    style="width:28px; height:30px; margin: 7px 5px; float: right;" />
                <p:menuButton value="#{visitorComponent.admin.admin_name}">
                    <p:menuitem value=" Dash Board"
                        action="#{visitorComponent.goHomePage}" icon="ui-icon-home" />
                    <p:separator rendered="#{visitorComponent.admin.role == 'admin'}" />
                    <p:menuitem value=" Admin Options"
                        rendered="#{visitorComponent.admin.role == 'admin'}"
                        action="#{visitorComponent.adminOperations}" icon="ui-icon-gear" />
                    <p:separator
                        rendered="#{visitorComponent.admin.passwordChangePermission == 'yes'}" />
                    <p:menuitem value=" Change Password"
                        rendered="#{visitorComponent.admin.passwordChangePermission == 'yes'}"
                        action="#{visitorComponent.gotoChangePassword}" icon="ui-icon-key" />
                    <p:separator />
                    <p:menuitem value=" Logout" action="#{visitorComponent.logout}" oncomplete="stopChat();"
                        icon="ui-icon-power" />
                </p:menuButton>
            </div>
            <!-- <p:blockUI block="j_idt18" trigger="homeBtn">
                <p:graphicImage name="icon/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </p:blockUI> -->
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
    <!-- <p:blockUI block=":homeBody" trigger=":homeBtn">
        <p:graphicImage name="icon/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </p:blockUI> -->
</h:body>
```

I need to block total template by click header link (home Button). It means By click home button I need to block total template page (I can able to block total header part).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean? Do you want to include same template in all pages

Comment: I done include, if I click button from header page then I need to block header and content total page but I am able to block only header page which was included in template. 
I need to block total template it means header, content and footer

Comment: Ok, you mean layout.

Answer (score 0):

Finally myself only did partially,

I am not able to block total page but I blocked main content. It means, In template I have code like below.

```
<ui:insert name="content">
                <ui:include src="content.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
```

In main page, we have to override this content page. There I have on